# Showing $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \left(z e^{\frac{1}{z}} e^{-\frac{1}{z^2}}\right)$ does not exists

Tags: limits

I want to show

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \left(z e^{\frac{1}{z}}  e^{-\frac{1}{z^2}}\right)$$

does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using the sequences
$$
z_n=\frac{1}{n}\to 0\quad\text{and}\quad w_n=\frac{i}{n}\to 0.
$$
Then
$$
z_n\exp\left(\frac{1}{z_n}-\frac{1}{z_n^2}\right)=\frac{\exp(n-n^2)}{n}\to 0
$$
while
$$
w_n\exp\left(\frac{1}{w_n}-\frac{1}{w_n^2}\right)=\frac{i\exp(-in+n^2)}{n}\to \infty.
$$